# Mixed Boolean Arithmetic Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to prove/derive the equivalence of the following formula:

$$
x*y = (x \land y) *  (x \lor y) + (x \land \neg y) * (\neg x \land y)
$$

whereas $(\land, \lor, \neg)$ correspond to bitwise operations over Boolean algebra ($B^n, \land , \lor, \neg)$ and arithmetic operations are in integer modular ring $Z/(2^n)$.

Rearranging by using DeMorgan rules gives me:
$x * (x \lor y) \land y * (x \lor y)$. However, I cannot simply factor out $(x \lor y)$ so I'm stuck at that point. The issue seems to be, that this whole thing is a **non-linear expression**.

I came across this identity in [this paper](http://www.nctatechnicalpapers.com/Paper/2006/2006-diversity-via-code-transformations-a-solution-for-ngna-renewable-security/download) and was wondering how one could derive/generate such identities.
Similar identities can be found in [Hackers Delight chapter 2](http://www.hackersdelight.org/basics2.pdf) (and are much simpler, i.e., linear combinations of the 16 boolean functions).

<s>Is it because the last term always equals to zero? How would one prove that?</s> The last term isn't always zero (e.g. $1*524288$).

**Example in $Z/2^{32}$**

$$
4 * 5 = (4 \land 5) * (4 \lor 5) + (4 \land \lnot 5) * (\lnot 4 \land 5)
\equiv (4) * (5) + (4 \land 4294967290) * (4294967291 \land 5)
\equiv (4) * (5) + (0) * (0)
\equiv 20
$$

**Update:**

Let's split the formula into the two parts for easier reference:
$$
t0 = (x \land y) *  (x \lor y) \\
t1 = (x \land \neg y) * (\neg x \land y)
$$

<s>I've used an SMT solver (z3) to prove that for all values of $x,y$ either $t0$ or $t1$ can be $\neq 0$, but not both at the same time.</s>

Counter example: $x = 1431655427, y = 427$

Comment: For Boolean vectors $x$, $y$, is $x*y$ componentwise multiplication (resulting in a Boolean vector), or is it dot product, or ...?

Comment: It refers to multiplication in the modular ring $Z/(2^n)$. Same goes for addition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note we have $x \land \neg y = x - x \land y$. Using this fact

$$(x \land y) (x \lor y) + (x \land \neg y) (\neg x \land y) = x y$$

becomes

$$(x \land y) (x \lor y) + (x - x \land y) (y - x \land y) = x y$$

expanding,

$$(x \land y) (x \lor y) + x y - (x + y) (x \land y) + (x \land y)^2 = x y$$

$$(x \land y) (x \lor y) - (x + y) (x \land y) + (x \land y)^2 = 0$$

Divide by $x \land y$:

$$(x \lor y) - (x + y) + (x \land y) = 0$$

$$(x \lor y) + (x \land y) = x + y$$

To prove this equality, write down $x$ and $y$ in binary: $x = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i 2^i$ and $y = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} y_i 2^i$, where $x_i, y_i \in \{0,1\}$. Note that $x \land y = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \min (x_i, y_i) 2^i$ and $x \lor y = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \max (x_i, y_i) 2^i$. We want to show

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i \max (x_i, y_i) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i \min (x_i, y_i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i x_i + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i y_i$$

which is the same as

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i (\max (x_i, y_i) + \min (x_i, y_i)) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i (x_i + y_i)$$

but for any numbers $x_i, y_i$ we have $\max (x_i, y_i) + \min(x_i, y_i) = x_i + y_i$.

Comment: Crystal clear proof. +1

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last part of the proof ("characteristic functions"), or point me to some information where this is explained in greater length?

Comment: @newgre: I have rewritten the last part to avoid characteristic functions, is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, all clear now. Thank you!